# My icon is 13x13 size and I got the warning "ToolWindow icons should be 13x13"

Tags: java, intellij-idea, icons, imageicon, intellij-plugin

I'm developing a plugin to IntelliJ and trying to set icon to my plugin.
My icon is 13x13 size but I'm still get the following warning:

> WARN - openapi.wm.impl.ToolWindowImpl - ToolWindow icons should be
>   13x13. Please fix ToolWindow

This is the code that sets the icon:

```
ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath() +
                    "icon2.jpg", "temp icon");
toolWindow.setIcon(imageIcon);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you check the correct image? What's the path you get? I'd assume there's a delimiter missing, e.g. either `/` or `.`.

Comment: The icon was loaded successfully, I can see the icon on the tool window. So I guess that the path is correct.
The only problem is the warning message.

Comment: The image might be resized to match the required dimension so please check whether the source image is really has that dimension. The warning itself might actually be about loss of quality if the image is resized, but that's just a guess.

Comment: The source image has the dimension 13x13.

Comment: was it resolved?

Answer (score 0):

Here i am  8 years later..

Managed get it working with:

`IconLoader.getIcon("/icons/myiconn.svg", MyClass::class.java)`